# How can I connect with Yahoo Messenger using other messenger softwares?

Tags: internet

Can I use other messenger softwares to connect with yahoo messenger? What type of messengers should I use? I am operation on Linux (Ubuntu 9.10) Operating System.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, try [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/), it's a multi-protocol messenger including Yahoo!.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the default chat client that's installed on 9.10 is Pidgin.  Either that, or the following ubuntu release.

Comment: I don't know, I'm not using Ubuntu. Pidgin does that work. Alazar doesn't have specified other than what, I thought other than the Windows version.